# EAS react native Change your app's target API level to at least 31

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play, android-app-bundle

I was uploading my AAB build to Google Play Store however, it is saying I should change the API level to 31 :

```
Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 31 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 31.
```

As I am using Expo (managed workflow) React Native and EAS I do not have the build.gradle file to change the buildToolsVersion to "31.0.0".

What should I do to upgrade the API level to 31 in this case? Should I do `expo upgrade` or `eas upgrade`?